# bash - How to match files names to use in loop

Tags: linux, bash

I want to run a loop command on each pair of files

```
a_xxx.wig
b_xxx.wig
c_xxx.wig

a_xxx.bed
b_xxx.bed
c_xxx.bed
```

I'd like to match the files based on sample name (a,b or c) and have the loop run a command through each of the pairs without having to do one at a time

```
for file in * do
bedtools intersect -a $sample.wig -b $sample > $sample.bed
done
```

Any ideas or pointers would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Those `.wig` and `.bed` files are all in the current directory?

Answer (score 3):

The `wig` file is the input, so just iterate over those. You can extract the portion of the file name to use as the "base" for the other names.

```
for file in *.wig; do
    sample=${file%.wig}
    bedtools intersect -a "$sample.wig" -b "$sample" > "$sample.bed"
done
```